# why is it coded by this way in leetcode?

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> hashtable;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            auto it = hashtable.find(target - nums[i]);
            if (it != hashtable.end()) {
                return {it->second, i};
            }
            hashtable[nums[i]] = i;
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

the above is the code in leetcode i saw,look at the "return {};" this line,i think that it is return a empty list,but it is astonish me that this function's return value is not empty and it is for working.can anyone explain to me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return {};` in this context is shorthand for `return vector<int>{};`

Comment: You might get a returned value from the other `return` statement inside the `if`, if you are seeing a non-empty `vector` returned from the function.

Comment: It constructs default returning value.

Comment: *can anyone explain to me why?* -- This is why sites such as LeetCode are not designed to teach C++.  Brace initialization has been part of C++ since C++11 (over a decade ago).

Answer (score 2):

> look at the "return {};" this line,i think that it is return a empty list

An empty vector to be precise, yes.

> but it is astonish me that this function's return value is not empty and it is for working.can anyone explain to me why?

Look at the other return statement:

> ```
> return {it->second, i};
> ```

That one doesn't return an empty vector.

---

P.S. Since the function always returns either 2 integers or 0 integers, `std::vector` is probably a poor choice for the return type.

Comment: thank you very much,i was too careless!